# Mac OS X command or script to zip all subfolders with a particular name

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zip

I have a folder containing many files and subfolders multiple levels deep.  I'm looking for a command or script that will zip any subfolder called "fonts", resulting in a fonts.zip file at the same level as the fonts folder.

The fonts folders should remain after creation of their zip files (no delete).

If there is a fonts folder inside another fonts folder (unlikely case), only the top-level fonts folder should result in a fonts.zip file (ideal, but not mandatory).

If there is already a fonts.zip file at the same level as the fonts folder, it should be replaced.

I'll admit, I'm a Mac newbie.  Hopefully there can be a simple terminal command to accomplish this.  But I'm open to other ideas how to accomplish this.

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: The `zip` program has many options (see `man zip`) but essentially you compress a directory recursively with `zip -r fonts.zip fonts`, and find all such source directories in a tree by using `find . -type d -name 'fonts' -exec zip -r fonts.zip {} +` (where `.` means the search starts from whichever directory you are in, in the terminal).  I do not however know offhand of a good way to "stop" if `fonts` appears more than once in a tree.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for the reply.  I tried the `find . -type d -name 'fonts' -exec zip -r fonts.zip {} +` command and the result was a single fonts.zip file in the starting directory.  Can it be modified to produce multiple fonts.zip files, each at the same level of its corresponding fonts folder?

Answer (score 0):

Using Kevin Grant's suggestion as a starting point, I was able to put together a terminal command that works the way I needed:

`find . -type d -iname '*fonts' -execdir ditto -c -k -X --rsrc {} fonts.zip \;`

I referred to the man pages for the find and ditto commands and their switches.  I chose to use ditto over zip because it is supposed to be more compatible with HFS and resource forks under Mac OS X.  Next I'll find out if StuffIt has a command line tool.  If so, I'll use it instead of ditto.

[This was also helpful.](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031118111144197)